# Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly (vert.x)

Tags: java, sql-server, vert.x

I am trying to insert data into a db. While inserting the data I am getting an issue from vert.x saying

```
   vertx 4.4.0 error => io/vertx/sqlclient/ClosedConnectionException

   vertx 4.3.8 error => Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly.
```

This **error** is occurring every-time on INSERT in DB.
But working on READ from DB

```
  public static MSSQLPool createMssqlDbPool(Vertx vertx, DbConfig dbConfig) {

    MSSQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MSSQLConnectOptions()
      .setHost(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_HOST", dbConfig.getHost()))
      .setPort(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_PORT", dbConfig.getPort())))
      .setDatabase(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_NAME", dbConfig.getDatabase()))
      .setUser(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_USER", dbConfig.getUser()))
      .setPassword(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_PASSWORD", dbConfig.getPassword()));

    // Pool options
    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
      .setMaxSize(5);

    LOG.info("DB connection : {}", connectOptions.toJson());

    return MSSQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

  }
```

> I have tried a lot of things
>
> 1. I added timeout from 3 seconds to 5 minutes but still getting the same error.
> 2. I tried creating a new user for DB, still it doesn't work.
> 3. I tried changing the version of the mssql-client.
> 4. When i run the same code in lower environments its workinf fine. It gives error only on production. So i am not sure if we need to do
>    changes in code or there should be some change in the DB side.

Now I am put of options as to why it is not working. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two solutions.

- We can reduce the version of mssql-client in vert.x to 4.3.1, which is compatible with the current RDS version of 15.00.4073.23.v1.
- Alternatively, we can keep the mssql-client version of vert.x at 4.3.8 and upgrade the production database's RDS version to 15.00.4236.7.v1.

Compatibility Chart

```
Ms-sql Client 4.3.8 RDS(Sql server) 15.00.4236.7.v1
              4.3.1                 15.00.4073.23.v1
```